# Change LOCALE_ID dynamically on angular

Tags: angular, localization

For example FB region setting supports 100s of Locales. How can we implement something like this on angular? does this mean we have to register all supported locales at development time?

[image]

Is there a way to change LOCALE_ID on angular without hardcoding setup work as follows and also dynamically change it. I am just after changing date time and number formats, language/text translation is not needed at the moment.

import localeFr from "@angular/common/locales/de";
registerLocaleData(localeFr, "de")

example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-locale-ywninm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

i am afraid default angular i18n is made in a way that you would be required to build angular app bundle for each locale. those /locales data will be auto imported by angular then. if it is not ok for you, use different i18n lib, the most popular one for angular is ngx-translate

Comment: but I only want to change datetime and number format. no text translation required.

Comment: LOCALE_ID is provided through DI, and there is no possibility to change any value in the angular DI, without recreating the DI subtree. I believe you still can provide LOCALE_ID on the application startup, and consume it from localStorage for example. but to change it, you would still be required to refresh the browser

Answer (score 0):

This solution work for me

```
        loadLocales(localeId){
          import(
            /* webpackExclude: /\.d\.ts$/ */
            /* webpackMode: "lazy-once" */
            /* webpackChunkName: "i18n-extra" */
            `@/../node_modules/@angular/common/locales/${localeId}`).then(module => {registerLocaleData(module.default)});
        
          }
    
    for calling function in component
    
    this.loadLocales('de') // fr
    
    // necessary import //
    import {registerLocaleData} from '@angular/common';
    import {  APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
    
    
    //Add provider //
    
    providers: [
        {
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: TestFunc,
          multi: true,
          deps: [CommonService]
         }
    ]

culture= service.culture; //'de-DE'

// for template ref //

{{ showDateStart | date: "EEE, MMMM d, y, HH:mm": '' : culture}} //culture
```

if you define it for your application then you add it into app.module.ts